# Relation between the cholesky upper triangular matrix of $A$ and the one of $A^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a symmetric, positive definite, real matrix (in short "spd matrix") and let $chol(A)$ be the upper triangular matrix obtained from $A$ by Cholesky decomposition.
Is there any relation between $chol(A)$ and $chol(A^{-1})$ that allows to transform the former into the latter (and/or viceversa)?

Clearly the relation $chol(A^{-1})$=$(chol(A))^{-1}$ does not hold. Is there any other known relation?

Thanks!

Comment: assuming $A=LL^*$ , $A^{-1}=R^*R$, then since $AA^{-1}=I$, $LL^*R^*R=I$ and $RR^*L^*L=I$, which $L(RL)^*R=I$, $R(LR)^*L=I$, since $A$ is pd, $L$ (resp $R$) is invertible, so $(RL)^*=L^{-1}R^{-1}$, $(RL)^*=(RL)^{-1}$, ie $RL$ is orthogonal

Comment: Ok, the product is orthogonal. But how can I recover R starting from L (and viceversa)?

Comment: well you asked for a relation, this is one, exploiting the symmetric property of $A$ (not exploited in my comment) may take you further

Comment: Well I asked for a functional relation, but probably I should have been more clear... Sorry! I'll edit the question.

Comment: Anyhow, right now, I can't see how symmetry of A (and its inverse) can help me recovering R starting from A,  can you give me a hint?

Comment: i dont know but play around with these relations and the properties given (symmetric/p-d), is this a homework?

Comment: No. That's a point to increase code efficiency for my PhD dissertation...

Comment: I admit I haven't already played around with the problem(I noticed the fact a few hours ago), I was just looking for someone that already had solved the same problem.

Comment: hmm, ok, in another context (blind source separation), one can adapt approximately the inverse matrix from the direct matrix using some relations, see for example S. I. Amari adapting the natural gradient rule, presumably it can be helpful